# Подсветка div блоков в Sublime 3?

Tags: css, вёрстка, sublime-text

Как поменять выделение div блоков в Sublime 3? 
Нужно чтобы была линия которая ведет от открывающего div к закрывающему div, как в notepad++.
Или хотя бы чтоб более яркого цвета выделение было(сейчас очень незаметная линия серая - тяжело находить конец-начало по ней).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: brackethighlighter, другого ничего вообще нет под сублим, я не нашел.

Comment: спасибо. Это плагин? Скачаю.

Comment: Отлично работает. Только не знаю как твой ответ выбрать лучшим или репутацию поднять.

Comment: добавил в ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плагин brackethighlighter, другого ничего вообще нет под сублим, я по крайней мере не нашел.
Ссыль https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter

Comment: хотя как описано он не выделяет элементы

Comment: @Geyan notepad++ тоже не выделяет элементы.